# How to run the 'source' command from file 'tasks.json' in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, sdk, vscode-tasks

I have a CMake C++ project which has a dependency on the SDK environment. Before running the CMake, I need to source the environment setup file.

```
source qemux86/environment-setup-i586-poky-linux
cmake ..
make
```

I created the [tasks.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix) file which has the above commands.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cmake build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "source qemux86/environment-setup-i586-poky-linux;cmake ..",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "make build",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build"
            },
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "-j3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "dependsOn": [
                "cmake build",
                "make build"
            ],
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It's working fine for me, but is there a way to run the [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source) command separately? Currently, I am running both the `source`
and CMake command in a single task.