# How to set up an environment using source command on a remote SSH Linux computer using Visual Studio Code tasks

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I want to cross-compile a project on a remote Linux PC for an embedded target, but it requires an environment setup.

I have an environment setup script. I can run this script on the remote Linux PC in the shell and it correctly sets my environments variables. The build script uses these environment variables and it successfully builds locally.

I connect to the PC with Visual Studio Code using the remote SSH Extension. I cannot seem to build in the external Visual Studio Code. The environment variables are not set even though I set up the environment via a task. The build script cannot find the right paths because of this.

Here is my *[tasks.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix)* file:

```javascript
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "env",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "source",
            "args": ["/opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.5-qt/environment-setup-armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi"]
        },
        {
            "label": "qmake frontend",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.5-qt/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/bin/qmake",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/frontend/frontend.pro", "-config", "release", "CONFIG+=imx6ul-linux"],
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
        },
        {
            "label": "build frontend",
            "dependsOn": [
                "env",
                "qmake frontend"
            ],
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
  }
```

I also tried the following, but it didn't help:

- *[How to run the 'source' command from file 'tasks.json' in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758116/how-to-run-source-command-from-task-json-in-vscode)*
- *[tasks.json support to reuse the same shell #168947](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168947)*
- *[How can I run a remote script before code starts? #6375](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6375)*

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to retrieve all the environment variables set by the environment setup script and convert it to the json format for taks.json in vscode:

```
env -i /bin/bash -c 'source <PATH_TO_SCRIPT>; printenv' | sed -En 's/(\w+)=(.*)/"\1":"\2",/p'
```

In this case:

```
env -i /bin/bash -c 'source /opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.5-qt/environment-setup-armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi; printenv' | sed -En 's/(\w+)=(.*)/"\1":"\2",/p'
```

You can store them in the global env section in tasks.json (after removing the last comma from the string):

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",

    "options": { 
    "env": {       
        "GDB":"arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gdb",
        "SDKTARGETSYSROOT":"/opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.5-qt/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi",
        "CPP":"arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E  -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.5-qt/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi",
        ...     
    }
    },              

    "tasks": [        

    ]
}
```

The command works the following way:

1. `env -i /bin/bash` starts bash without any existing environment variables (see [Sanitize environment with command or bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671027/sanitize-environment-with-command-or-bash-script))
2. `/bin/bash -c 'source /opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.5-qt/environment-setup-armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi; printenv' |` exports environment variables and prints/pipes them to the next command
3. `sed -En 's/(\w+)=(.*)/"\1":"\2",/p'` does regex substitution to convert it to JSON format
4. last comma needs to be manually removed and the text needs to be pasted into the JSON tasks.json

Example of regex substitution
`echo -e "A=10\nB=11" | sed -En 's/(\w+)=(.*)/"\1":"\2",/p'`
or https://regex101.com/r/JgRrkg/1

Produces

```
"A":"10",
"B":"11",
```

Now there is no need to run the env task and all other build tasks see the correct paths and other environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is with the environment setup not persisting across tasks in Visual Studio Code. As far as I know, each task in Visual Studio Code runs in its own isolated environment, so environment variables set in one task are not carried over to other subsequent tasks.

You can try running a Bash shell and within that shell you can execute the environment setup script using `source`. Then, you run the `qmake` command and `make` commands sequentially.

By doing this, the environment variables set in the environment setup script should be available for the entire build process.

Answer (score 0):

The sharing of the environment depends on how Visual Studio Code handles the console, i.e., whether it reuses it or not.

You can create a Bash script with all these commands, which is one way to avoid depending on Visual Studio Code's undocumented behaviors.

Create *run_build.sh* and put it under `${workspaceFolder}`.

```
source /opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.5-qt/environment-setup-armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
/opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.5-qt/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/bin/qmake ./frontend/frontend.pro -config release CONFIG+=imx6ul-linux
```

File *[tasks.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix)* could be:

```javascript
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build frontend",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "run_build.sh",
      "problemMatcher": [
          "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

If you don't want to create a new script, just combine them in `tasks.json`.

```javascript
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build frontend",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "source <env configuration>; qmake <arguments go here>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This works, but only if the arguments are not in args. Also vscode doesn't see the paths. I'm looking for a solution that uses tasks, but scripts.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the benefits of using a task rather than a script. I'm not sure what you mean by "vscode doesn't see the paths" and just for guessing, you want to path the `$workspaceFolder` to `qmake`. If I'm right, here goes a more complete example:
`"command": "source opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.5-qt/environment-setup-armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi; /opt/fslc-framebuffer/2.5-qt/sysroots/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/bin/qmake ${workspaceFolder}/frontend/frontend.pro -config release CONFIG+=imx6ul-linux"`

Comment: But the "source" line is not actually two lines, is it?

Comment: @PeterMortensen You are right. VSCode executes shell-type tasks by `bash -c <command>` one by one. I can't come up with an idea to fulfill the requirement of "using separated tasks". BTW, thanks for reformatting the answer~